# Secure login to a SQL Server database from C# application

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, security

I have a question and I cannot find an answer. I'm programming Windows Forms application in C#. I'm using Entity Framework to connect to a SQL Server database. As I see a password to the database is stored in my connection string. I create users in my application and then I store them in a database table.

I know that is not a secure way to do it, because the password can be stolen from my connection string and I can't control which user made which change in the database. I thought that maybe creating accounts in SQL Server for each user in my application is a good idea. Then I can fill connection string with user password when he logs. But how can I check if login is correct when I don't have an access to the database in that moment yet?

Thanks in advance,

Artur

Comment: You could use a domain account. The account that runs the application also has right to read/write to the database.

Comment: If it is a windows form app, how do all users share the same DB?

Comment: DB is on a server.

Answer (score 0):

Create a domain service account and connect via "Integrated Security"=true or sspi, if it is True it connects with windows account configured, if it is sspi then it will connect thru current windows login, if it is false then we need to provide userid and password.

Based on provider,

SqlClient -
Integrated Security=true;
-- or --
Integrated Security=SSPI;

OleDb -
Integrated Security=SSPI;

Odbc -
Trusted_Connection=yes;

OracleClient -
Integrated Security=yes;

Comment: But please tell what can I achieve doing that? I need a possibility of creating new accounts for users in my application.They should know their passwords to have possibility to log in. My application will be installed on many computers and using this application users will be able to make changes in database(located in the Internet).